# EC2 Micro Instance CPU spikes to 100% at regular interval every day

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

[image]

I know Amazon throttles micro instance if it uses up certain number of CPU time, but I don't think this is the case. All the spikes appear at around 6:30 to 6:40 UTC. I checked my cron job and there is nothing scheduled for that time:

```
@reboot ~/path/to/script1.sh >> ~/log/cron.log
0 13 * * * ~/path/to/script2.sh >> ~/log/cron.log
```

What else could it be?

PS: Notice the CPU Utilization dropdown is set at "Maximum". The graph looks similar for "Average".
PPS: This instance is part of a 2-instance load-balanced setup.

Here's what's inside my /etc/cron.daily (the other crons are empty):

apport, apt, aptitude, bsdmainutils, dpkg, logrotate, man-db, mlocate, passwd, popularity-contest, standard, update-notifier-common

Comment: Have you tried checking the logs around that time?

Comment: Also, it could be something configured with something other then cron, or a custom daemon.

Comment: which os you are using? could be process of updatedb

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I did check my HTTP logs, there is nothing unusual. What other logs should I check?

Comment: @neo Ubuntu. How do I check for updatedb? No database installed in this server, btw.

Comment: `updatedb` is the script that builds the database for the `locate` command to help you find files. You might want to check in the `/etc/cron.d/` dir as it will show you some of the scripts that are running at odd times. As well as any `/etc/cron*/` dirs.

Comment: Your system log, in `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: @GeekNum88 I updated my question with what's inside cron.daily

Comment: the updatedb is initiated by /etc/cron.daily/mlocate
you can try to remove it and check the spike

Comment: @neo Instead of removing `mlocate`, can I modify `/etc/crontab` so cron.daily happens at some other time?

Comment: yes. 
vi /etc/crontab

usually it runs on 06:25. updatedb is the culprit if you have many files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually, Ubuntu AMIs on Amazon have their daily cron jobs under `/etc/cron.daily` scheduled for morning hours. This schedule is managed using `/etc/crontab`. Here's how a sample `/etc/crontab` looks like:

```
$ cat /etc/crontab 
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

Clearly, daily tasks run at 6:25am. You may want to tweak these settings to move daily tasks to some other time if this is impacting direct delivery of your server(s). Further, you could investigate items under `/etc/cron.daily`. For me, it looks like:

```
$ ls /etc/cron.daily/
apport  apt  aptitude  bsdmainutils  dpkg  logrotate  man-db  mlocate  popularity-contest  standard
```

Out of these, typically `man-db` and `logrotate` may take up major CPU time for execution. These are standard tasks and can be tweaked for optimum performance. You may want to look into tuning your logrotate and man-db policies.

Hope this helps.